# How to use apostrophe (') in xpath?

Tags: selenium

HTML:

```
<div class="h-padding-h-tight h-margin-b-default">
<button class="Button__ButtonWithStyles-y45r97-0 kqnQCZ" data-test="checkout-button">I'm ready to check out</button></div>
```

Selenium:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;     
String obj= "I\'m" +" ready to check out";
WebElement readyCheckout = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[text() ='" + obj+"']")); 
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", readyCheckout);
```

Also tried it but get the same error:

```
WebElement readyCheckout1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@text\"I'm ready to check out\"]"));
```

> org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: Unable
> to locate an element with the xpath expression //button[text() ='I'm
> ready to check out'] because of the following error: SyntaxError:
> Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string
> '//button[text() ='I'm ready to check out']' is not a valid XPath
> expression.

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking for help with your solution to the problem, edit your question and ask about the actual problem. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
WebElement readyCheckout = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[text() = \"I'm ready to check out\"]"));
```

Here how you can fix your notation:

```
String obj= "I'm ready to check out";

WebElement readyCheckout = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[text() = \"" + obj + "\"]"));;
```

Comment: None of them has worked. Third code commented out after xpath( because of single quote i guess. Second quote has a bug. I fixed it by putting double quote like I did originally shown above.

Comment: My bad the third one was for JS, I deleted it it. I had a minor mistake in the first and second one which I fixed now. I tested them and they work.